# Check if child elements width has exceeded parents width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a menu where, the last item it exceeds it's parents width.

How can I detect if the child element has exceeded it's parent width with jquery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple example:

```
var child = $('.child');
var child_w = child.width();
var parent_w = child.parent().width();
if(child_w > parent_w) {
    alert('AHHHH!');
}
```